# Add multiple images in multiple sheets

Tags: python, dataframe, openpyxl

```
n = 2+len(ind)    
sheets = wb.sheetnames
for hc_sh in range(len(ind)):
    HC_sheets = wb[sheets[n+hc_sh]]
    active = wb[sheet2[hc_sh]]
    print(active)
    img=Image("Histogram1.png")
    active.add_image(img, "F1")
    wb.save(path)
```

I have Histogram1, Histogram2, Histogram3 images. I need to paste those 3 in 3 excel sheets of path. In this above code, I'm able to put Histogram1 in all 3 sheets. How can I put all 3 images at a time in 3 sheets?

2nd Code edited:

```
hi=pd.read_excel(path,sheet_name=sheet2,index_col=0)
di_hi=list(hi.values())
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path) 

for p, hc in enumerate(di_hi,1):
    df_hc=pd.DataFrame(hc)
    plot=df_hc.plot(kind='bar')
    plot=plt.xlabel("Probe Name")
    plot=plt.ylabel("Fold Change")
    plot=plt.axhline()
    plt.savefig(f'Histogram{p}')
    
n = 2+len(ind)    
sheets = wb.sheetnames
for hc_sh in range(len(ind)):
    HC_sheets = wb[sheets[n+hc_sh]]
    active = wb[sheet2[hc_sh]]
    for fill in range (len(ind)): 
        filename = f"Histogram{fill+1}.png"
        img=Image(filename)
        active.add_image(img, "F1")
        wb.save(path)
```

Comment: repeat the relevant lines for the other 2 images? Alternatively use another `for` loop if you have more the 3 images and it becomes cumbersome to manually repeat these lines.

Comment: But Image function only taking .png file, I'm not able to give as variable name. Is there any way like that?

Comment: You are free to hardcode whatever filename, or use a variable containing  whatever filename that you define in a loop, e.g. `for i in (1,2,3): filename = f"Histogram{i}.png"`

Comment: With the 2nd code which I have edited now, all 3 images is getting pasted in all 3 sheets. How can I correct that?